# foreach grabing the last element of a object array - why 0 retrieves it?

Tags: php

```
foreach ($videoFeed as $key => $videoEntry)
{
  if ($key == 0) {
     $flashUrl = $videoEntry->getFlashPlayerUrl();
  }
}
```

The videosFeed contains the last videos of a given youtube feed.

If I upload a video I know that the last uploaded video will be the one that as the key 0.

The only reason for this is because, on the feed list, the first element is the last video, and that is defined on the youtube side right?

Comment: Right. Oh and I retagged to PHP.

Comment: I don't understand at all what is asked here

Comment: You don't need a `foreach` loop for what you're doing, you can directly access the entry as `$videoEntry = $videoFeed[0];`

Answer (score 0):

yes, i agree with you the ordering of $videoFeed must be due to the api you get it from - youtube's.

Commenter is right, unless you are doing more in that loop there is no need for it.  just use $videoFeed[0]